# Least number of commands to rebase private branch

Tags: git, rebase

I'm still in the process of getting confident with Git so am still treading carefully with some elements of it.

The list of commands I have for rebasing my private branch as I work (so it does not become out of date by the time I'm finished) is:

```
# Prepare the new private branch
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout -b new-feature
# work, commit, work commit, time to rebase...
git checkout develop
git pull develop origin
git checkout new-feature
git rebase develop
# continue working...
```

What I'm wondering is if I can save a few steps and do the following when I want to rebase:

```
# on the new-feature branch
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
# continue working....
```

Or will that cause problems when I come to merge my private branch with develop?  If it's ok, do I need to merge origin/develop with develop if I've already done that in my private branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fetch-and-rebase as outlined is just fine.  For the second question, I'm not quite sure what you're asking, so the below covers all bases, as it were.

(Note that `git pull` is mainly just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, unless you configure it to do `rebase` for instance.  I'm going to use only `git merge` below, on the assumption that you've done a sufficiently-recent `fetch`.)

Here's what you'll get, assuming ongoing activity on `origin/develop` and a starting point at commit D1 on origin/develop:

```
... - M6                          <- master, origin/master
        \
         D0 - D1                  <- develop, origin/develop
                \
                 N0 - N1          <- HEAD=new_feature
```

Now you do `git fetch` and "they" have added D2 and D3.  I'll leave out master and origin/master, assuming they haven't moved (if they have it doesn't matter anyway), leaving more room for local stuff:

```
        D2 - D3                   <- origin/develop
       /
D0 - D1                           <- develop
       \
        N0 - N1                   <- HEAD=new_feature
```

So now (with `HEAD=new_feature`, all pointing at commit `N1`) you do:

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

and git does this, making two new commits `N0'` and `N1'`:

```
                N0' - N1'         <- HEAD=new_feature
               /
        D2 - D3                   <- origin/develop
       /
D0 - D1                           <- develop
       \
        N0 - N1                   [abandoned]
```

The abandoned commits eventually fall away (I'll leave them out below) and meanwhile you add `N2`, and they add `D4`.  So, you `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/develop`, giving:

```
                N0' - N1' - N2    [abandoned]
               /
              |     N0''-N1''-N2' <- HEAD=new_feature
              |     /
        D2 - D3 - D4              <- origin/develop
       /
D0 - D1                           <- develop
```

As before, the "abandoned" stuff can be forgotten-about, which gives you a nice clean history of your changes (however many times rebased) extending out from the end of `origin/develop`.

At any point along the way you can, but do not have to:

```
git checkout develop && git merge origin/develop && git checkout new_feature
```

Since you haven't added any commits onto `D1`, this just fast-forwards, so that `develop` points to the same commit as `origin/develop`.

Let's say you haven't manipulated the local `develop` yet, but it's time to merge in `new_feature`, and you now have this:

```
                    N0''-N1''-N2' <- HEAD=new_feature
                    /
        D2 - D3 - D4              <- origin/develop
       /
D0 - D1                           <- develop
```

Presumably you'll want to merge up through commit `N2'` in the above diagram with the endpoint of `origin/develop`.  You can certainly do this now:

```
git checkout develop           # get HEAD onto develop breanch
git merge origin/develop       # fast-forward local develop branch
```

which gives you this (I'll straighten out the kink between `D1` and `D2`):

```
                    N0''-N1''-N2'     <- new_feature
                    /
...D1 - D2 - D3 - D4                  <- HEAD=develop, origin/develop
```

but the more interesting question is, do you want the final result to be:

```
                    N0''-N1''-N2'     <- new_feature, HEAD=develop, origin/develop
                    /
...D1 - D2 - D3 - D4
```

or should it look like this:

```
                    N0''-N1''-N2'     <- new_feature
                    /            \
...D1 - D2 - D3 - D4 ------------ M   <- HEAD=develop, origin/develop
```

?  If you want that merge commit `M`, your final `git merge` command will need a `--no-ff` argument, and you need to get the local `develop` pointing to commit `D4` first.  In that case, you *must* do the fast-forward merge to get the `develop` label to point to `D4`:

```
git checkout develop           # set HEAD=develop
git merge origin/develop       # fast-forward develop to origin/develop
git merge --no-ff new_feature  # create merge commit M on local develop
git push origin develop        # and push local develop to origin/develop
```

If you *don't* want the merge commit, though, it doesn't matter where `develop` is pointing when you do the final `merge`, as it is just going to fast-forward.  So, instead, you would do this:

```
git checkout develop           # set HEAD=develop
# git merge origin/develop     # optional: not needed, but harmless
git merge new_feature          # fast-forward local develop to new_feature
git push origin develop        # and push local develop to origin/develop
```

It's always a case of figuring out "what commit graph do I want to end up with" first.  If you can draw the graph you want, it's a lot easier to figure out how to get there from wherever you are now.

Comment: This is a much more thorough answer I had hoped for.  Thank you so much.  Your very last set of commands was the answer to my final question.  But I'm grateful for the extra clarity you've provided.