# What happens to feature branch after merge with master in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am confused with git merge.

Suppose i have `feature` branch taken from `master` and they have divergedliek this
and they merged like this

[image]

Now i want to know that what will be the diagram after this command

```
git checkout master
git merge new-feature
```

1. What will be the diagram after this command

   `git checkout master`
   `git merge new-feature`

   provided after that i dont close feature branch after that and just do one more commit after that on feature branch

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is: nothing happens to the `feature` branch as a result of the merge.  The new merge commit is added on the current branch (which is `master` when the merge is done).  No existing commit is affected, as no existing commit can ever be changed at all.

As an aside, the arrows between commits really should point the other way.  New commits point back to older commits; older commits can never be modified, not the least little bit, so there's no way to "add an arrow" to an older commit.  You can only make a new commit, which then has one or more back-pointing arrows, to one or more older commits.  (One arrow per pointed-to-commit, that is.  You can even make a new commit with *no* back-pointing arrows: this is a new "root commit".  That's a bit more of an advanced thing, though, and not all that common in repositories.)

Although the ASCII art version is not as pretty, these are the same before and after diagrams:

```
        o-o     <-- feature
       /
o--o--o--o      <-- master
```

[becomes:]

```
        o-o     <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--o--o   <-- master
```

If you then check out `feature` and add another commit to `feature` after this, it becomes:

```
        o-o--o  <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--o--o   <-- master
```

---

Edit: let's re-draw that last picture (same picture, we'll just put a name `m1`, for "merge #1", in place of one of the `o`s representing a commit):

```
        o-o--o  <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--o--m1  <-- master
```

Now suppose you continue developing away on `feature`, adding two more commits:

```
        o-o--o--o-o    <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--o--m1         <-- master
```

and then decide to merge `feature` into `master` again.  To do this, git will need to make a new merge commit, `m2`:

```
        o-o--o--o-o    <-- feature
       /   \       \
o--o--o--o--m1------m2 <-- master
```

The merge base for the *new* merge is derived by looking at the *old* merge, so that git can tell that only the three latest `feature` commits need to be brought in.

This is why, if you decide that something from `feature` has broken `master` and you "undo" it before adding merge `m2`, you need to manually "redo" it if needed.  That is, suppose that after making merge `m1` but before adding the three new commits on `feature`, you find that `master` is broken and you add a commit `f` ("fix by removing a piece of feature"):

```
        o-o         <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--o--m1--f   <-- master
```

Now you go ahead and work in `feature` as before, adding the three commits:

```
        o-o------o-o-o    <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--o--m1--f         <-- master
```

Now when you go to `git merge feature` into `master`, git will again find the base, and know just to take the changes from the three newest commits and add them to `f`:

```
        o-o------o-o-o    <-- feature
       /   \          \
o--o--o--o--m1--f------m2 <-- master
```

But commit `f` deliberately disabled part of the new features.  You may have to manually fix up the merge (either before making commit `m2`, or in a separate commit after `m2`—how you want to do it is up to you) that "undoes" the fix in `f`, re-enabling the full feature.

---

Regardless of whether and when `feature` is to be merged back into `master` again later, you can choose whether or not to merge `master` into `feature`.  Let's assume for instance that there's something especially `G`ood in `master` that *should* be brought into `feature`:

```
        o-o        <-- feature
       /   \
o--o--o--G--m1     <-- master
```

Here you can just:

```
git checkout feature && git merge --no-ff master
```

to bring the changes in `G` and `m1` into `feature`.  Of course the changes in `m1` are already there, but git can figure this out itself, so it will really only bring in the good stuff from `G`:

```
        o-o----m2  <-- feature
       /   \  /
o--o--o--G--m1     <-- master
```

The `--no-ff` is only needed if you want an explicit merge commit, which is useful for making the development line of "feature" stand out.  If you leave out `--no-ff`, git will observe that bringing `m1` into `feature` results in, well, `m1`, and will just move the branch label in a "fast forward" operation:

```
        o-o
       /   \
o--o--o--G--m1     <-- feature, master
```

If you're "on branch feature" (`git checkout feature`) and make a new commit, that will leave the label `master` pointing at `m1`, and `feature` pointing at your "new newest" commit:

```
        o-o
       /   \
o--o--o--G--m1     <-- master
              \
               o   <-- feature
```

I put `feature` down below to emphasize that it's not obvious that the "top" `o-o` line was once on `feature`.

Note that this graph is the same as this alternative drawing that looks a bit like a snail:

```
        o-o    o   <-- feature
       /   \  /
o--o--o--G--m1     <-- master
```

which kind of hints that the `o-o` *might* have been on feature; but is very different from *this* drawing, which includes `m2`:

```
        o-o----m2--o  <-- feature
       /   \  /
o--o--o--G--m1        <-- master
```

and which makes it very clear that `feature` has an unbroken lineage going back to the earlier top `o-o`.  This is basically what "other direction merging with `--no-ff`" is for.

(Do you want it?  Well, that depends on *you*, really.  Graphs like the "snail" one are very common, and you get used to them and knowing which branch-label was on some commit sequence some time in the past is often not very useful.  But sometimes it is useful, and then you want the graphs that look more like tents and geometric things, rather than snails. :-) )

Comment: thanks, this is what i was mistaking, i thought that when i merge then   feature branch also gets the commit from master, so it means if i have to keep continuing on feature then i have to merge master in feature branch also?

Comment: You don't *have* to merge `master` back into `feature` unless you want to pick up new stuff from `master`.  If you just keep developing on `feature` and later re-merge `feature` into `master` again, the "merge base" is the last point at which it was merged into master.  I'll add a bit to the diagrams.

Comment: actually `feature` is my local branch where i do all the stuff and then i pull latest stuff from master and then first merge my stuff with master and push master too server and then i also want to have master stuff so i need to merge master on `feature` branch. is there nay better way for that?

Comment: thankyou very much , i wish if  i could vote you more

Comment: What `rebase` does is make *copies* of commits: essentially, "see what got changed in some commit over there, make a copy of it applied to this other commit here".  If you do this for one commit, it's considered a "cherry pick".  If you do it for a whole *chain* of commits, then move the old label, it "looks like" you somehow moved the commits.  You didn't really (they were *copied*).  This is fine if they're private to you, not so great if you shared the old copies.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18525176/1256452 for more.

Comment: "no existing commit can ever be changed at all". That's not entirely true, we do have `reset` and `revert` commnands.

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk: `git reset` lets you point a branch name anywhere, effectively discarding commits entirely. That doesn't *change* them! Meanwhile `git revert` makes a *new* commit, which doesn't change the old ones either. Think of commits as uniquely identified by their hash IDs, *not* by branch names, because that's how it really works internally. Since humans tend to work by branch names, discard-history-and-rebuild can work for us, making it *seem* as though commits changed—but they really didn't!